# How can I install libpcap header files on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, apt, libpcap

How can I install libpcap header files on Ubuntu 12.04?

When I use `apt-get install libpcap` I receive following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpcap
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with libpcap?

Comment: I get source code needs `libpcap`. It uses `libpcap` to capture network packets.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use this:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

Comment: That's because 1) libpcap-dev (probably) depends on the libpcap package, and will bring it in and 2) if you have source code that needs libpcap, you not only will need the libpcap package (whatever it's called - its name might be "libpcap0.8", for various Debian reasons), which provides shared libraries for already-built programs that use libpcap, but you will also need the libpcap-dev package, which provides header files needed to compile the source code for programs that use libpcap (and static libraries in case people want them).

Answer (score 7):

to install libpcap. try these commands

```
cd /usr
mkdir nembuild
cd nembuild    
wget http://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.5.3.tar.gz
tar -xf libpcap-1.5.3.tar.gz
cd libpcap-1.5.3
./configure
make && make install
```

Enjoy!!!

Comment: Why install a package while there is a binary (RPM, DEB , ...) package for it? Your method is the most complex way dude!

Comment: because libpcap 1.5.3 is way better than the version 0.8 available from aptitude

Comment: Aptitude does not use 0.8, it is only the name of a package. Check "apt-cache show libpcap-dev" to see the version used.

Answer (score 5):

To install libpcap open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8 libpcap0.8-dev libpcap-dev
```

Comment: According to [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libpcap-dev) `libpcap-dev` depends on `libpcap0.8-dev` and itself depends on `libpcap0.8`. So `libpcap0.8` is redundant.