# How to prevent other hosts on the same network from cutting of my internet connection?

Tags: networking

Recently, I've noticed that my Internet connection -- wireless on a public WiFi network -- has been cut off many times, and I think this may have been done maliciously or deliberately (for example, by users running Netcut on different systems).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is this your network? [NetCut](http://www.arcai.com/arcai-netcut-faq/item/62-netcut-209-free-download-official-site-windows7-support.html) is a windows tool designed to prevent arp spoofing - what does this have to do with Linux in general and Ubuntu specifically?

Comment: I'm a new Ubuntu user , i am on a public network .I wish that i can stop other users (net-cut was just an example of how  a  windows or Unix user may  cut my Internet connection ) on the same network from cutting of my connection . Sorry for my English.

Comment: Well can't you just give me a straight answer without complexing the subject ? .( I know it is a public network because it is my school's network and I'm being kicked off by other students )

Comment: We can't give you an answer without understanding the question.

Comment: Well i did my best with explaining my question : ( i want to protect my computer's connection from being spoofed by other users on the a network that i have the right to use it but it is not mine - a public "Wifi" -  ) it is already solved by installing Arpon but i had a problem with installing Libpcap ( one of his libraries )  .I hope that i made my question very clear , if you have another solution i would like to test it . Thanks !

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem;  let's act immediately!

You need (and **should**) to use a configured [`arpON` daemon](http://arpon.sourceforge.net/) in all your personal computers and, if you are the network administrator, you can (and should) upgrade to a router with *Internal Firewall* and *Peer Isolation*.

**NOTE**: Always use encrypted (at least WPA) networks to have a layer of extra protection and privacy; public networks are very often insecure and you should warn immediately the administrator if you find vulnerabilities & problems, also in institutional networks.
Please note that arpON is very heavy and must be configured and tested: follow **only** the [official guide](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=it&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.ubuntu-it.org%2FSicurezza%2FArpon&act=url) and the `man` pages in your Ubuntu distribution!
Ask by commenting down here if you need more help (safety & privacy are very important) and don't forget to press the UP arrow and set as favorite if I'm of any help. ;-)
Have a nice experience,
good evening!

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! .Is arpon works only against tux-cut or any other ARP attacks ?

Comment: Arpon secures the entire ARP protocol, so it prevents almost any known ARP attack against your Linux/Unix machine and other Linux/Unix machine with arpon installed and well configured. Remember that - obviously - it will not secure the gateway device (ex. router, hub ecc.) but only the PCs with the daemon installed and only the ARP protocol packets between those PCs; it is not a firewall but only a network daemon. I suggest to always keep your computer updated, configure a real firewall on your PC and use safe networks.

Comment: i followed the tutorial  on the link that you gave me I'm having a problem with the command " cmake ./ "Found Kernel Version 3.11.0-18-generic

-- Linux Distro:  Ubuntu

-- Found libpthread.
-- Found libdnet.
-- Found libnet.
CMake Error at cmake_modules/FindPCAP.cmake:39 (message):
   libpcap not found! Please visit http://www.tcpdump.org/ or see in the arpon 'INSTALL' file.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (find_package)

Comment: Arpon is a good security software that requires the libpcap deep packet analysis library; you may or may not have it. If you don't (it's your case) follow this answer: 'http://askubuntu.com/questions/347788/how-can-i-install-libpcap-on-ubuntu-12-04' ; IF it doesn't function visit http://www.tcpdump.org/#latest-release and download the tar.gz source package on your machine, then build it by following this basic guide: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/install-from-source/ 
Please note that packets built from source may not be supported directly by the askubuntu community. Good luck.