# how to install different library files

Tags: 12.04

i want to install libcoap in my ubuntu os. but every time i write "

> > sudo apt-get install libcoap-dev

it gives error that libcoap is not found.

> > E: unable to locate package libcoap-dev

similarly i made a user defined library, it gives same error for it. I tried to upgrade openssl version but same error for installing libraries. 
i have placed folder containing lib files on desktop and i am working in desktop directory, still it gives same statement. what to do??
where i need to place my library files for installation.

Comment: Do you mean libcap?

If so, type

`sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install libpcap header files on Ubuntu 12.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/347788/how-can-i-install-libpcap-header-files-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

You can only `sudo apt-get install` packages which are available in the package sources of your system. You can search the default package archive of your Ubuntu version at: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

It seems that the library you need is not available in any package archive for Ubuntu, yet. Your best bet will thus probably be to get the sources manually as described on the website of the library: https://libcoap.net/doc/install.html